# Is it possible to store image to firebase in android?

Tags: android, firebase

I have tried with converting uri object to string, but that won't work (obviously).
If it is possible, can you tell me how or give me some links to watch some tutorial?

Comment: This was asked a few hours ago. Please search for an existing question before entering your own.

Comment: *Firebase just released a new feature called [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/). This allows you to upload images and other non-JSON data to a dedicated storage service. We highly recommend that you use this for storing images, instead of storing them as base64 encoded data in the JSON database.*

Comment: Yes firebase storage is a good option for storing images but can you give a reason to not store images as base64 encoded data in the JSON database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes Firebase supports storing images, since they're only binary files.

All you need to do is to convert your image to `base64` then store it like any other data.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Then to display your image :

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
myimageview.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```